# Its outputs details incorrectly in php/html

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to display all the questions from the drop down menu when the user selects `All` from the question drop down menu and output it underneath. Problem is that it is not doing this and to make it worse, it is giving me undefined offset errors stating:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: ... in .... on line 605
```

Line 605 is:

```
echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
```

My question is how to fix the error and display all the questions if user selects `All` option?

I have a demo you can go through: [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text29.php)

Follow steps below:

- In Module drop down menu, select System Stratergy and submit
- When Assessment drop down menu appears, select POKUB1 and submit
- You will see students and question drop down menu. You can see that if you open up the drop down menus that there are 3 students and 2 questions. Please select a single student and `All` questions and ubmit. This is where you will see the errors when really I want to display all of the question's details here.

CODE:

Question Drop down menu:

```
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value=23">1</option>
<option value=32">1</option>
</select>
```

Below is code which determines display depending on which options are selected from question drop down menu.

```
    function StudentAnswers()
        {

        $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
            SELECT
            sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
            QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
            GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
            FROM Student st
            INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
            INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
            INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
            INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
            LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
            LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
            ";

            // Initially empty
            $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
            $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
            $parameterTypes = 'i';


            // Check whether a specific question was selected
            $p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?'':$_POST["question"];

            switch($p_question){
            case 0:
                //dont' add where filters
                break;
            default:
                $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
                $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
                $parameterTypes .= 'i';
            }

            // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
            // our query
            if(!empty($where)) {
                $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
                global $mysqli;
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
                // You only need to call bind_param once

                if (count($where) == 1) {
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
            }
            else if (count($where) == 2) {
                $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
            }


            }

            $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
              GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
              ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
            ";

        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentId,$detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,$detailsQuestionNo, 
        $detailsQuestionContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,$detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,
        $detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark);    

        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
        $selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows(); 


            $question = array();

            while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

            $arrQuestionNo = array();
            $arrQuestionContent = array();



            $arrQuestionNo[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsQuestionNo;
            $arrQuestionContent[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsQuestionContent;



            $questions[] = $arrQuestionNo;
            $questions[] = $arrQuestionContent;

        }

        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->close();

        ?>

...........................................................................................

    <h2>STUDENT'S ANSWERS</h2>

    <?php   

              foreach ($questions as $key=>$question) {

    echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;

    }
    }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Student Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
 `StudentId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `StudentForename` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `StudentSurname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `StudentAlias` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `StudentEmail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `StudentUsername` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `StudentPassword` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `StudentDOB` date NOT NULL,
 `Year` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `CourseId` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`StudentId`),
 KEY `FK_Course` (`CourseId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Question Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Question` (
 `QuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SessionId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionNo` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionContent` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `NoofAnswers` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `ReplyId` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionMarks` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `OptionId` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`QuestionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=357 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question an hour ago? And ... try to copy less code, and more important snippets, nobody wants to read a few pages of code to find (for example) a typo.

Comment: @VladPreda It is similar code but different question. I got told to separate my questions so I asked one issue in one question and this issue in this question. I will reduce code, I just wanted you all to know the structure of my code

Comment: At Helios School of Computing and Engineering they need to teach you *how to debug and to understand the codes you write*. You're  explaining the problem as though you're a site user ("I selected", "It shows"), but not a programmer who wrote the very code. A programmer have to be able to follow the program logic and compare the actual results with expected ones. In terms of variable values and control flow, not in literary terms like "it doesn't show up".

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610396/how-to-display-all-details-if-user-selects-all-option

Comment: @user1914374 : Can you please show your table structure?

Comment: @Roger Are you talking about php/html table structure or db table structure for student and question?

Comment: @user1914374: The db structure

Comment: @Roger included in update

Comment: @user1914374 You need to re-factor your code to make it easier to debug (separate DAL, logic and view from each other, forget about procedural scripting and use OO structures (especially, [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), use already existing design patterns like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). BTW, if you just want to hide notification you can simply check if index is defined: `...htmlspecialchars((isset($arrQuestionNo[$key])?$arrQuestionNo[$key]:''))...`

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.......

```
$question = array();

while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {
    // assuming you don't need the StudentId
    $questions[] = array('no' => $detailsQuestionNo,
                         'content' => $detailsQuestionContent);
}
```

and

```
foreach ($questions as $key => $question) {
    echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' . 
         htmlspecialchars($question['no']) .
         ': ' . 
         htmlspecialchars($question['content']) . 
         '</p>' . 
         PHP_EOL;
}
```

## EDITED

Or you can try this if your grouping by question:

```
$question = array();

while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {
    if (true === isset($questions[$detailsQuestionId])) {
        $questions[$detailsQuestionId]['students'][] = $detailsStudentId;
    } else {
        $questions[$detailsQuestionId] = array();
        $questions[$detailsQuestionId]['no'] = $arrQuestionNo;
        $questions[$detailsQuestionId]['content'] = $arrQuestionContent;
        $questions[$detailsQuestionId]['students'] = array();
        $questions[$detailsQuestionId]['students'][] = $detailsStudentId;
    }
}

foreach ($questions as $questionId => $question) {
    // $question['no']
    // $question['content']

    foreach($question['students'] AS $key => $studentId) {
        // $studentId
    }
}
```

## Or if your grouping by userID...

```
$students = array();

while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {
    if (false === isset($students[$detailsStudentId])) {
        $students[$detailsStudentId] = array();
    }
    $students[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionId] = 
                                       array('no' => $arrQuestionNo,
                                             'content' => $arrQuestionContent;
}

foreach ($students AS $studentId => $questions) {
    // $studentId
    foreach ($questions AS $questionId => $question) {
        // $questionId
        // $question['no']
        // $question['content']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop is iterating over the `questions` array, which was filled in with:

```
        $questions[] = $arrQuestionNo;
        $questions[] = $arrQuestionContent;
```

This means it's an indexed array, not an associative array; the keys are 0 and 1.

But then you echo `$arrQuestionNo[$key]` and `$arrQuestionContent[$key]`. These are associative arrays, whose keys are student IDs, not indexes starting from 0 (unless you happen to have students with these ID numbers).

Also, you initialize `$arrQuestionNo` and `$arrQuestionContent` to an empty array each time through the fetch loop. So when you're echoing the results at the end, these just contain the questions from the last row that was fetched.

You should use a multidimensional array:

```
while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {
  $questions[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionNo] = $arrQuestionContent;
}
```

Then your printing loop should be:

```
foreach ($questions as $studentId => $studentQuestions) {
  echo '<h2>Student '.htmlspecialchars($studentId).' Answers</h2>'. PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($studentQuestion as $questionNo => $content) {
    echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($questionNo). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($content). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Comment: `An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.` So technically speaking any array in PHP is associative, is not it?

Comment: Yes, they're technically the same, but they're _conceptually_ different.

Comment: @Barmar I am assuming then that I need to change `$arrQuestionNo[ $detailsStudentId ] = $arrQuestionNo` to `$arrQuestionNo[] = $detailsQuestionNo;`. Same for `$arrQuestionContent` as well?

Comment: Those arrays are not needed. The problem was that they only allowed one question per student. That's the source of much of your problems. Everything is in `$questions`.

Comment: So for `$arrQuestionNo` for example, to recognise that `$detailsQuestionNo` belongs to `$arrQuestionNo`, what do I need to include in while loop for this? Do I simply do `$arrQuestionNo[] = $detailsQuestionNo` after `$questions[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionNo] = $arrQuestionNo;`?

Comment: There is no `$arrQuestionNo` any more. Just use `$questions[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionNo]`, its value is the content of the question.

Comment: So if I want to add extra question details such as optionType, replyType, NoofAnswers etc, don't I need to include something so it recognises its an option type, or a reply type etc. See where I am confused in your code is I don't know how you got `$arrQuestionContent` to display question content, or how if I add `$arrReplyType`, how can I get it recognise that the question's reply type `$detailsReplyType` goes into that variable?

Comment: If you want to do that, you should make an `$question[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionNo]` an associative array, whose keys are strings like `'content'`, `'optionType'`, `'replyType'`, etc. Then you access `$question[$detailsStudentId][$detailsQuestionNo]['optionType']`. This technique keeps all the information about a question together in one object, instead of scattered among lots of different arrays.

Comment: We need to put a stop to this. Stack Overflow is not the place for tutoring on programming principles. Extended discussions like this should be avoided.

Comment: Ok, I think I have enough information in being able to understand this. Thanks