# How to display all details if user selects 'All' option

Tags: php, mysqli

Below I have 2 HTML drop down menus, one for students and other for questions:

```
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="2">What is 2+2</option>
<option value="34">What is 3+3</option>
<option value="42">What is 4+4</option>
<option value="51">What is 5+5/option>

</select>  


 <select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="23">Jay Hart</option>
    <option value="32">Bubba Wright</option>
    <option value="43">Tim Grey</option>
    <option value="52">Mary Pine</option>
    </select>
```

Below is a mysqli query which will output results depending on the options chosen from the two drop down menus above:

```
 $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
    SELECT
    sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
    QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
    FROM Student st
    INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
    INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
    ";

    // Initially empty
    $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
    $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
    $parameterTypes = 'i';

    // Check whether a specific student was selected
    if($_POST["student"] != '0') {
        $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }

    // Check whether a specific question was selected
    // NB: This is not an else if!
    if($_POST["question"] != '0') {
        $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }

    // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
    // our query
    if(!empty($where)) {
        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
        global $mysqli;
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
        // You only need to call bind_param once

        if (count($where) == 1) {
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
    }
    else if (count($where) == 2) {
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
    }
    else if (count($where) == 3) {
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
    }

    }

    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
      GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
      ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";

.......................................................................................

    $arrStudentId = array();
    $arrStudentAlias = array();
    $arrStudentForename = array();
    $arrStudentSurname = array();
    $arrQuestionNo = array();
    $arrQuestionContent = array();


    while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {
    $arrStudentId[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsStudentId;
    $arrStudentAlias[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsStudentAlias;
    $arrStudentForename[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsStudentForename;
    $arrStudentSurname[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsStudentSurname;
    $arrQuestionNo[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsQuestionNo;
    $arrQuestionContent[ $detailsStudentId ] = $detailsQuestonContent;

}

          foreach ($arrStudentId as $key=>$student) {

echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;


}
```

Now the details output with no problems if I select a particular student or a particular question from the respective drop down menus as the db is able to retrieve the values from those drop down menus as they are actual ids in the db.

But the issue is if I select an `All` option from either drop down menus. The value of the `All` option in both drop down menus is `0`. Now `0` is not in the db as an id, what I wanted to do is that if the user selects the `All` option, then it displays `All` the student details if selected in student drop down menu,  `All` the question details if selected in the question drop down menu.

Now the query is working in gathering the data to do this as it uses the dynamic WHERE clause built to include the appropriate conditions. But my question is how can I get it to display all the details of students/questions if the user has selected the `All` options in the relevant drop down menus?

UPDATE DEALING WITH RING0 ANSWER:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in ... on line 358

Warning: mysqli::prepare(): (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' in ... on line 360

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ... on line 370
```

CODE UPDATED:

```
    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
    SELECT
    sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
    QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
    FROM Student st
    INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (st.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
    INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
    ";

    // Initially empty
    $where = array();
    $parameters = array();
    $parameterTypes = '';

    // Check whether a specific session was selected
    if($_POST["session"] != '0') {
      $where[] = array('q.SessionId = ?');
      $parameters[] = array($_POST["session"]);
      $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }

    // Check whether a specific student was selected
    if($_POST["student"] != '0') {
        $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }

    // Check whether a specific question was selected
    // NB: This is not an else if!
    if($_POST["question"] != '0') {
        $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }

    // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
    // our query
   if(count($where) > 0) {
    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    global $mysqli;
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
    // You only need to call bind_param once

if (count($where) == 1) {
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
}
else if (count($where) == 2) {
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
}
else if (count($where) == 3) {
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
}
```

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

As you can see above, it shows I selected on student but I have chosen `All` Qustions. Yet it only displays one question under the `Student Answer` heading, in this example, the total number of questions which you can see in the brackets is `2`, so it should show 2 questions, not one question

DB SCREENSHOT:

Slightly shortened version of normal query but this would not affect main query as that too shows same number of rows. It shows 2 rows as there are two questions. The results below is for a single student `StudentId = 1`, All questions in Assessment 26 (`SessionId = 26`).

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you're using `$detailsStudentId` as the key in your result arrays, each row for a student overwrites the previous one. Just display the details as you fetch them, don't put them in an array. Or make it a 2-dimensional array, keyed by student ID and question number.

Comment: See my answer in the linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382607/its-outputs-details-incorrectly-in-php-html?lq=1. It shows how to do this using a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the value could be both All or '0', you could do a switch

```
<?php

//check if POST is empty

$p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"];

switch($p_student){
case 'All':
case '0':
    //dont' add where filters
    break;
default:
    $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
    $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}

$p_question = empty($_POST["question"])?'':$_POST["question"];

switch($p_question){
case 'All':
case '0':
    //dont' add where filters
    break;
default:
    $where[] = 'q.questionId = ?';
    $parameters[] .= $_POST["question"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}
```

Remember that sometimes it's a **GET** when the page is directly accessed or refreshed at later time.

So maybe you need a **$_REQUEST**['student']

Placed the whole code, with my answer merged in
https://github.com/fedmich/StackOverflow-answers/blob/master/14610396/index.php

Comment: Sorry about the `All` an `0`, I forgot to change the html from `All` to `0` as that HTML was a old html I used before changing it to `0`. In the real app it is `0`. I will test your answer

Comment: Do I need to to remove the `if (count($where) == 1) {`... and rest of code as well when including your solution?

Comment: yes, I think you should avoid using that if (count($where) == 1) {, because its too generic, in the future you might be adding another **where[]** above it.

Comment: Just one more question before testing, I also have a question drop down menu which is coded in similar way as student drop down menu, does the same statement then become  `switch($p_student, $p_question){`?

Comment: no you'll need to make 2 switches then http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php. let me update my answer

Comment: You gonna have to post me what the whole code should look like because including the switch statements means no results is being outputted at all when selecting All

Comment: You should try to learn how to quickly compare codes by using  http://winmerge.org/about/screenshots/
 or if you examine the Github I just create to see how the "diff" or History there.
Keep on learning and reading the official PHP documentation too. +1 if you put more efforts; you'll get the rewards of your hardworks soon enough :)

Comment: I had to go for ring0 method because by using the switch method, it did not remove the where clause condition if user sleect all in either student or question drop down menu. Anyway though it is still not displaying all student details and all questions when selecting the `All` option in relevant drop down menus. Any ideas why? The database output the correct rows so there must be something wrong with my php loop

Comment: You can use either switch or if ifelse, doesn't matter. but you should really learn switch, sometimes it will come in handy, and your code can be easy to read. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Yes but my issue is not that now, my issue is if I select `All` questions for example, how can I display all questions, at moment it is only displaying one question, not all questions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23932/discussion-between-fedmich-and-user1914374)

Comment: Have you seen my last message in discussion?

Comment: Hi, still not quite getting it working, it is displaying one question only rather than all questions, I have changed code little bit and shortended it slightly, do you want to see code? You can look at updated demo in link if you wish to see what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you provide, I noticed the following:

- The "All" value in the *options* is set to "All" while it should be "0"
- *Session* is selectable, while the PHP code doesn't check if a *session* has been selected
- There is no *question* select in the HTML code you showed

It seems all you have to do is change the *value* for "All" in your *Selects*, and add some code for *Session*. And I added a "question" to fit the problem.

- Change all the Option value for "All", set to "0":

Code:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="2">EOWOW</option>
<option value="34">EOWOW</option>
<option value="42">EEMOO</option>
<option value="51">EDOOS</option>
</select>  


<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="23">Jay Hart</option>
...
```

and also for "Question" that doesn't appear in the HTML code

```
<select name="question" id="questionDrop">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">What is the 50th State?</option>
...
```

- Add the test code for *session*

Add some code to empty arrays, and to check if session is selected

```
// Initially empty
$where = array();
$parameters = array();
$parameterTypes = '';

// Check whether a specific session was selected
if($_POST["session"] != '0') {
  $where[] = 'q.SessionId = ?';
  $parameters[] = $_POST["session"];
  $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}

// then same code

// Check whether a specific student was selected
if($_POST["student"] != '0') {
    $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
    $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}
...
```

This way the 3 *Selects* are checked in the PHP code, and their value is "0" when "All is selected.

The *where* code should be

```
if(count($where) > 0) {
    global $mysqli;

    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
    // You only need to call bind_param once

    if (count($where) == 1) {
      $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
    }
    else if (count($where) == 2) {
      $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
    }
    else if (count($where) == 3) {
       $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
    }
}
```

**edit2**

In

```
if($_POST["session"] != '0') {
  $where[] = array('q.SessionId = ?');
  $parameters[] = array($_POST["session"]);
```

remove the `array`s:

```
if($_POST["session"] != '0') {
  $where[] = 'q.SessionId = ?';
  $parameters[] = $_POST["session"];
```

Comment: Sorry about the `All` an `0`, I forgot to change the html from `All` to `0` as that HTML was a old html I used before changing it to `0`. In the real app it is `0`. I will test your answer

Comment: I have included an updated which is specifically for you as it includes code from your solution. I am receving some errors

Comment: @user1914374 Edited the *where* code, replacing `!empty($where)` with `count($where) > 0`

Comment: Please see edit2: since we are checking *session*, it needs not to be arrays

Comment: Sorry my fault but the session drop down menu shouldn't have an `All` option, that should be a please select option. I apologise for that. The session drop down menu should be the question drop down menu. I editted this. The WHERE Session = ? is the default where clause, no mater which option is chosen from student or question drop down menu, it should always see which session was selected by using this default where clause. Would this mean you need to change your answer? Again apologies for my incompetence

Comment: Yes that is All, I really should get to sllep as its 4:30 am where I am but need to get this done before I can lol. The `Please Select` is just for the session drop down menu which you don't have to worry about. THe student and question drop down menus contains `All` option

Comment: I think I have essed something up in my for loop whic you can't see in code, I will edit this and get back to you in couple of hours to let you know whats happening. But the errors are gone

Comment: my issue is simply now how to display all questions if user selects `All` from question drop down menu. So if there are 5 questions in drop down menu (excl `All` option), then if user selects `All` option, it will display all of the 5 questions. At moment it is only displaying 1 question. The query retrieves all the questions, so I am assuming I am messing up the foreach loop and arrays?